# Multiple UITableView Scrolling Synchronization

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two UITableView, while one table view scrolling i have to scrolling another tableview.

1. I achieve that functionalities with getting the contentOffsetOf one tableView through

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

and pass that value to another tableView and change that tableView contentOffset using this value. its working which i expected. the same way if i scroll another tableView it will pass the new contentOffset to this table and it will change its contentOffset according to the value.

but, when ever i change the contentOffset of one tableView using the value of another tableView contentOffset again its calling its

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

so its working like two way communication. but i don't want while i am changing the contentOffset value using the another tableView contentOffset, it should not call again that should not call back the same function. how can i achieve.

Comment: give both the tableview tags and handle by if condition. Like If(tableview.tag==1)

Answer (score 0):

Set a BOOL values
`shouldChangeContentOffsetOfTable1` and `shouldChangeContentOffsetOfTable2`

for each table in the method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` to `NO`

and in the method

`-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to `YES`.

Then in the method

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

check this value for each table and if it NO, dont't set it's content offset. So, the contentOffset of each table will not be setted, if this table is being scrolled manually.